# Adjoint of the Coupled Covariant Derivative on Spinors

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian, gauge-theory, spin-geometry

I want to understand the proof for a $C^0$ bound of solutions to the Seiberg-Witten equations.
Among other places, it can be found in Kronheimer, Mrowka: "The genus of embedded surfaces in the projective plane", it is Lemma 2 therein.
One step in the proof goes as follows:
$$
\Delta \left| \Phi \right|^2
=
2 \langle \nabla_A^* \nabla_A \Phi , \Phi \rangle - 2 \langle \nabla_A \Phi, \nabla _A \Phi \rangle.
$$
(This step with context is provided in the picture below)
The proof that this is true comes from using the definition $\Delta = - \sum_i \nabla_i \nabla_i$ and using that $\nabla_A$ is metric.
But I'm puzzled by the result.

> Why is the right hand side not constant $0$?
>   It should be, as $\langle \nabla_A^* \nabla_A \Phi , \Phi \rangle=\langle  \nabla_A \Phi , \nabla_A \Phi \rangle$ by the definition of adjoint.

[image: Source for action of Laplacian on a product of spinors]

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact context, I would bet that $\nabla^*$ is not a pointwise adjoint on each fiber, but rather it is the $L^2$ adjoint, meaning $$\int \langle \nabla^* \phi , \psi \rangle = \int \langle \phi , \nabla\psi \rangle,$$
and since the theorem is about a $C^0$ bound you are working pointwise.

I don't know if it's as simple to define a pointwise adjoint for a differential operater, because $\nabla \phi$ depends on the local behavior of $\phi$.